# giving aws console management access for an IAM user , using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am creating an IAM user and attaching a policy with boto3 ,

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.client('iam')
user = iam.create_user(UserName='test_user')

iam.attach_user_policy(UserName='test_user',PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam:12345667644:policy/test_policy')
```

user got created successfully , but It doesn't have console management access . I tried searching for some api calls like `users.set_credentials` or similar from [official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html) and other places ,but not successful so far. Can someone please let me know the correct to set up this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the official Boto3 IAM docs, and searched for *"console"* and I see [this method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_user) which appears to be what you are looking for: `create_login_profile`

> Creates a password for the specified user, giving the user the ability to access AWS services through the AWS Management Console.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark , it was exactly what I was looking for :)